# Is it worthwhile to make side-firing ships?

Tags: stardrive

The Kulrathi start off with armor technology and have hulls that have large capacity on the sides. I tried to design a side firing ship because there are options to have ships "keep enemy at x side". It was too slow and the enemy fighters carouselled around to its weak side.

Many weapon modules can have their field of fire rotated to face the sides as well, so I thought this would be something feasible. Once you unlock shield technology ships become fast enough to resolve agility as an issue, but with shields side-firing strategy doesn't make sense.

**Is it possible to design a side-firing ship that is as capable as a front-firing ship?**

Answer (score -1):

No, as every ship in game is designed as front firing ships, of course it is possible to create guns on sides. but its pretty useless